# Nodejs Redis Client Listeners

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, queue

I have a server.php in the below.I want to have listener on my channels so that I can get realtime data for my website.I have attached the structre of my redis.

[image: My Redis]

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const Redis  = require('redis');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
var routes = express.Router();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


bluebird.promisifyAll(Redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(Redis.Multi.prototype);


var Client =
    Redis.createClient({
        host:'159.89.5.229',
        port:'6379',
        socket_keepalive : true,
        prefix:'resque:',
        retry_strategy: function (options) {
            if(options.error && options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED'){
                return new Error({'Code':99,'Message':'Connection Lost On Redis'});
            }
            if(options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60){
                return new Error({'Code':100,'Message':'Retry Time Exhausted'});
            }
            if(options.attempt > 10){
                return undefined;
            }
            return Math.min(options.attempt * 100 , 3000);
    }
});
Client.subscribe('resque:queue:default');
Client.on("subscribe",function (channel,count) {
    console.log(channel + count);
});

Client.on('message',function (chan,msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});

Client.on('error',function (err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

In addition , if any message comes to my channel like queue -> resque:queue:default I want to know. Any ideas ?
Btw I'm new at redis.If any mistake I'm sorry

Comment: You have subscribe already in your code.  If you publish to that channel, you'll receive that.  You can read more about pub/sub here: https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Comment: so in my case if anything enters the resque:queue:default , should I get it now ? @dzm I'll check the link

Comment: Not unless you `publish` to that channel.  Are you using https://github.com/resque/resque?

Comment: yes I'm using resque @dzm

Comment: That's a ruby library? I assume you're using the PHP port? In any case, if your trying to get functionality that is part of resque, you need to use the library.

Comment: So I'm using php-resque and In order to achieve I need to use that library in nodejs ? is that right @dzm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158335/discussion-between-mehmetali-sarac-and-dzm).